# Gridstack not updating height properly inside iframe

Tags: iframe, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0, gridstack

Here I'm using an iframe to display a page-in-page that contains a Gridstack grid-based editor to reposition its elements. The inner page should consist of plain HTML and CSS. All gridstack-related CSS and any ko-related JS calls should be made from the outer page. I works on a single page.

Now the problem is that as soon as I the **Gridstack** grid into an **iframe** and bind it to a viewmodel. It doesn't size properly. The widgets are **present in the HTML**, but **not visible** (due to **zero-height**)

In this case the Knockout binding gets executed, but the **CSS height attribute** and **vertical Y-position** fail to get computed dynamically.

**Note**: the **width** and **horizontal X-position** get assigned correctly, because they are loaded from a static CSS class.

**Update**: Probably to fix this one needs to override this function found inside Gridstack. It dynamically creates CSS in the outer page and not the inner. This could be the cause of the problem:

```
createStylesheet: function(id) {
            var style = document.createElement('style');
            style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
            style.setAttribute('data-gs-style-id', id);
            if (style.styleSheet) {
                style.styleSheet.cssText = '';
            } else {
                style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));
            }
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);//POSSIBLE CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM
            return style.sheet;
        },
```

[The snippet bellow still won't execute, I recommend looking at my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ux5suyu1/6/)

```js
//WORKAROUND TO SKIP THE SAME-ORIGIN POLICY
$('#editor-iframe').load(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('#editor-iframe').contents().find('html').html('<head><title></title><style type="text/css">.grid-stack { background: lightgoldenrodyellow; } .grid-stack-item-content { color: #2c3e50; text-align: center; background-color: #18bc9c; } </style><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/troolee/gridstack.js/master/dist/gridstack.css" /></head><body><div class="grid-stack" data-bind="gridstack: widgets"><div class="grid-stack-item" data-bind="attr: {\'data-gs-x\': $data.x, \'data-gs-y\': $data.y, \'data-gs-width\': $data.width, \'data-gs-height\': $data.height, \'data-gs-auto-position\': $data.auto_position}"><div class="grid-stack-item-content"><button data-bind="click: $parent.deleteWidget">Delete me</button></div></div></div></body>');
    
    //THE ACTUAL CODE
    ko.bindingHandlers.gridstack = {
      init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context);

        return {
          controlsDescendantBindings: true
        };
      },
      update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
        var widgets = valueAccessor(),
          grid = $(element).gridstack().data('gridstack'),
          afterAddWidget = function(items) {
            var item = _.find(items, function(i) {
              return i.nodeType === 1;
            });
            grid.addWidget(item);
            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(item, function() {
              grid.removeWidget(item);
            });

            //RESIZE IFRAME TO FIT NEW CONTENT
            var iframeWin = document.getElementById('editor-iframe').contentWindow;
            $('#editor-iframe')
              .height(Math
                .max(
                  iframeWin.document.body.scrollHeight, iframeWin.document.body.offsetHeight,
                  iframeWin.document.documentElement.clientHeight,
                  iframeWin.document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
                  iframeWin.document.documentElement.offsetHeight) + 'px');
          },
          newVA = function() {
            return {
              data: widgets,
              afterRender: afterAddWidget
            };
          };
        ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, newVA, allBindingsAccessor, data, context);
      }
    };

    var Controller = function(widgets) {
      var self = this;

      this.widgets = ko.observableArray(widgets);

      this.addNewWidget = function() {
        this.widgets.push({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          width: Math.floor(1 + 3 * Math.random()),
          height: Math.floor(1 + 3 * Math.random()),
          auto_position: true
        });
        return false;
      };

      this.deleteWidget = function(item) {
        self.widgets.remove(item);
        return false;
      };
    };

    var widgets = [{
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: 2,
      height: 2
    }, {
      x: 2,
      y: 0,
      width: 4,
      height: 2
    }, {
      x: 6,
      y: 0,
      width: 2,
      height: 4
    }, {
      x: 1,
      y: 2,
      width: 4,
      height: 2
    }];

    var controller = new Controller(widgets);
    ko
      .applyBindings(
        controller,
        document
        .getElementById('editor-iframe').contentWindow.document.body);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/troolee/gridstack.js/master/dist/gridstack.js"></script>

<iframe id="editor-iframe" src="http://stacksnippets.net" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="width:100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: Interesting: if I add a css min-height, they show up and have a resize handle, but upon resizing, they snap back to their minimum height. Their width is normal.

Comment: When you do that they are being spread up differently than in the original example. http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/demo/knockout.html

Comment: Update: deep inside Gridstack there is a call made `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);`, which appends the newly generated styles to the head of the outer page and not the inner. This could be the problem. I'm looking for some way to modify that function.